# Capture piped value (Noob Question)

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-scripting

I need to capture a value and don't know how to do it.

myData
|> Seq.count

How do I capture that count?  I want to be able to do an if on it or whatever.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I think you'll want Seq.length to determine the length of a sequence:

```
let n = {1..42} |> Seq.length
if n > 10 then printf "Too many numbers!"
```

Answer (score 3):

Since some collections (e.g., array) have a Length property which can be used to efficiently check for empty, I thought I'd mention, if that's what you're going for, `Seq.isEmpty` is what you want. `Seq.length` is O(*n*).